# I am confuse in managing hierarchical data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, tree

I'm reading this link [managing hierarchical data in mysql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)  because I'm doing MLM project. The example show this.

[image]

but I'm confuse in the lft and rgt. I want to put the id's of my members  who registered in the MLM. I just followed the pattern of the example in managing hierarchical data in mysql.

something like this.,so the lft and rgt values are the id's of my regisitered members.

**tree_table**

```
id    parentid         lft       rgt

1        1              2         3

2        3              4          5

3        4              6           7

4        7              8           9
```

I run this SQL

```
 SELECT node.parentid,node.lft,node.rgt
    FROM tree_table AS node,
            tree_table AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
      AND parent.parentid = '1'
    ORDER BY node.lft;
```

but it gives me only 1 record,it did not show all his children or downlines.here is the output

```
 parentid   lft   rgt
   1         2     3
```

here is my structure table

```
CREATE TABLE `tree_table` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `parentid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lft` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `rgt` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Please help me thank you in advance.

Comment: It would have been more helpful if the person who downvoted explained *why* they were downvoting. Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @AdamCameron:Hi,he has 2 answers with nested set. Look in his history.  He should take his time. Vote to close!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the "and parent.parent.id=1" in the query. The data is a nested set a.k.a celko tree.

Comment: I could not filter if I will remove that,the puprpose is to show all  the children ,example parentid 4 so it will show 6, 7, 8 and 9

Comment: Its a nested set. You need the left and right value.

Comment: @ashTon:left and right value is from a depth-first traversal. But the values you give is totally wrong. Its also not needed when you have a parentid. That's why I ask if its homework. You should mark it as homework. A nested set is expensive but sometimes faster.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do initially is to read Joe Celko's article on "[Trees in SQL](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html)", and nested set theory in general (Wikipedia does a reasonable job: "[Nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)"). It does take a bit of practise and reflection to get a handle on it.

The first thing you seem to be misunderstanding is that the left/right values do not relate to the key values, they are completely separate entities. What they do is - in concert with each other - reflect the hierarchy of data.

The left/right values of a node define the boundaries of the left/right values of its descendant nodes. Taking your sample code as an example: `Flash` is a descendant of `MP3 Players` as its left/right both fall within the range defined by `MP3 Player's` left/right. Simialrly *all* the subsequent nodes are descendants of `Electronics`, as all their left/right values fall within its left/right range.

Conversely an ancestor of a given node is one whose left/right values fall completely outwith the node in question's left/right. `Electronics` is an ancestor of `Flash` because the range 1-20 is outside (or surrounding) the range 12-13.

A node that has adjacent left/right values - like `Flash` - implicitly has no descendents: there is no width to its range for descendants to fit into.

Nested sets are very quick to fetch all ancestors or all descendants, but not so excellent at fetching immediate parents, children or siblings. To that end, sometimes it's also good to include a `parent` value, which denotes the *ID* of the parent node. So we have a hybrid nested set / adjacency list model there. There is more overhead in maintaining the tree (C_UD, not not R operations), but in a web environment, reads overwhelm writes by orders of magnitude, so this is generally OK.

Your basic problem seems to be you are thinking the `left`/`right` values relate to the record `ID` values, which they do not.

Go read those articles, and do some deskchecking with your data, and it should start making sense. It is not completely straight forward though, so give yourself some time.

One caveat to using nested sets though: understanding how the hierarchy is reflected is only part of it. You also need to understand the operations necessary to read ancestors, descendants, parents, children, siblings; and you *also* need to understand the algorithms necessary to add/update/delete nodes. These are non-trivial, and will require further reading still. But explanations of those are outwith the scope of this question.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply,..just want to ask where does the lft and rgt values came from ?where do we get those values,in the links you provided they are already given.,I don't know how can I apply this to my application to have values to lft and rgt and where should I get?

Comment: I am looking to my regsiter form and I don't know what values should I insert to lft and rgt if I will save a new record or register a new member

Comment: Like I said, @ashTon, this is a complex topic. You need to do the reading, understand it, do the requisite desk work and experimentation. No amount of me typing is going to teach you this stuff, you need to learn it. Holding tutorials on nested set theory is outwith the scope of a Stack Overflow Q&A. You simply need to do the actual work to learn it.

Comment: @AdamCameron:Or just a depth-first-traversal? Why so complicated?

Comment: @Phpdna can you pls use sufficient words so that one doesn't have to be inside your head to know what you're on about? ;-) You get 500-odd chars to play with in a comment: don't be afraid to use 'em.